# passing parameters between forms

Tags: forms, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

Hi everyone i'm trying to passing parameters between forms but i have this error:
frm-92101 there was a failure in the forms server during startup.
I wanna place a button on the EMPLOYEE form that when pressed, will call the EMPLOYEE/DEPENDENT form and automatically query the dependents for the employee being viewed on the EMPLOYEE form.
Icreated the EMPLOYEE Form and add a button.I assigned a trigger when bouton pressed :

```
DECLARE
    pl_id   ParamList;
BEGIN
    pl_id := Get_Parameter_List('tmpdata');
    IF NOT Id_Null(pl_id) THEN
        Destroy_Parameter_List( pl_id );
    END IF;
    pl_id := Create_Parameter_List('tmpdata');
    Add_Parameter(pl_id, 'EMPLOYEESSN', TEXT_PARAMETER, :SSN);
    Run_Product(FORMS, 'empdepn', SYNCHRONOUS, RUNTIME,
    FILESYSTEM, pl_id, NULL);
END;
```

After that i add a parameter into the EMPLOYEE/DEPENDENT
I created a PARAMETER called EMPLOYEESSN with the code bellow and add a parameter EMPLOYEESSN and add a  WHEN-NEW-FORM-INSTANCE trigger :

```
DECLARE
    blk_id Block;
BEGIN
    -- Obtain the block ID of the EMPLOYEE block.  This is the
    -- Master block in the empdepn master/detail form.
    blk_id := Find_Block('EMPLOYEE');
    IF NOT Id_Null(blk_id) THEN
        -- Check to make sure our parameter has a value. If this form
        -- were executed by itself, then the parameter will be null.
        -- If this form is called from EMPLOYEE then the parameter will
        -- be passed along and assigned to: PARAMETER.employeessn
        IF (:PARAMETER.employeessn is not null) THEN
            -- Since we have a parameter, use it to alter the WHERE Clause
            -- property so that it becomes WHERE ssn=:PARAMETER.employeessn
            SET_BLOCK_PROPERTY(blk_id,DEFAULT_WHERE,'ssn=' || : PARAMETER.employeessn);
            -- Navigate to the EMPLOYEE block and execute a query automatically
            GO_BLOCK('EMPLOYEE');
            EXECUTE_QUERY;
        END IF;
    END IF;
END;
```

Any idea please, thanks for help

Comment: Do you need to use RUN_PRODUCT?  Why not just use OPEN_FORM?

Comment: Hi,thank you for your response i used run_product because i need to pass the  pl_id like a parameter? Can i dot it with the OPEN_FORM?

Comment: Yes the on-line help for Forms shows various calling syntaxes for OPEN_FORM including `PROCEDURE OPEN_FORM(formmodule_name VARCHAR2,activate_mode NUMBER,session_mode NUMBER,paramlist_id PARAMLIST);`

Comment: Hi, when i replace the RUN_PRODUCT with OPEN_FORM by this code : OPEN_FORM('empdepn', 1, 1,  pl_id) i don't move to the empdepn form;by the way i have already add the full path for the empdepn form.any idea please?

Comment: If your forms are in the location identified in config as FORMS_PATH (I think) then you don't need to specify the path in the OPEN_FORM command.  I'm afraid it's a while since I used Forms so my memory of the details is a bit hazy!